# How to sync Steam savegames?

Tags: steam

I've been playing a couple of games on my Surface Pro 2 while travelling. When I launched a game on my desktop after I got home, I noticed my savegames did not sync.

While I realize Steam couldn't sync while I didn't have access to the internet, I did turn my Surface on after I got back home. Steam simply didn't bother syncing then, so I was forced to launch each game I had played so Steam would sync.

Having to launch every game while an internet connection is available is quite inconvenient, especially when some games have unskippable intro videos. Is there an option where I can tell Steam to sync all savegames without having to launch a game?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is not. Steam only syncs games to the client, when being restarted, but not from the client to the cloud. You are required to launch the game once for that to happen.

Answer (score -1):

[GameSave Manager](http://www.gamesave-manager.com/) is an excellent solution for syncing really any save games - it doesn't exclusively work for Steam. Despite that, it has excellent support for many games on steam, and it's easy enough to sync games that GSM doesn't immediately recognize.

The way I use this program is it's default sync method - it will essentially turn your save game folder into a "shortcut" pointing to your preferred cloud storage method. For me, that's Dropbox, so the moment I save my game, it's uploaded to my Dropbox storage. I can also sync game content, I.E hundreds of MBs of Sims 3 content, Fallout mods, you name it.

Version 3 of this program is stable and what I would recommend using. The author is currently working on version 4 and has a public preview out.

Comment: Disclaimer: i dont downvote this answer, but i think it is because question ask for forcing steam sync, not for 3rd program to do it...

Comment: @Lyoneel thank you for the info. That's a shame, because it really is a great program and solves OP's problem. About as good of an answer as he's going to get imo.